# A Ravenous Riddle

Tags: cipher, poetry

I’ve lost a phrase in here, can you find it?

> *O*nce upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, w*e*ak and weary,
> Ov*e*r many a qu*a*int and curious *v*olume of forgotten lore—
> Wh*i*le I *n*odded, nearly napping, *s*uddenly there came a tapping,
> As of some one gently *r*apping, rapping at my chamber door.
> “’*T*is some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door—
>             Only t*h*is and *n*othing more.”

The Raven by E. A. Poe

Hint 1

> *This*

Hint 2

> Word Scramble

Please say how many hints you used.

Comment: The hint specifically says "word scramble" which is misguiding... word scramble usually means one word.

Comment: @smlee, I used word scramble because the phrase was scrambled. There’s no Phrase Scramble/Words Scramble tags.

Comment: no worries, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full Disclosure:  I violated the NO-COMPUTERS tag

Hint 1:

> Italicized letters oeeavinsrthn

Hint 2:

> I used the Internet Anagram Server and get a heck of lot of results.  The most interesting and fitting is:  **HE'S INTO RAVEN**   but I'd really need some sort of hint in the body of the question to have any degree of certainty.

Comment: The no computer tag  was more so that you couldn’t look up an answer. My original answer I put in was rot13(GUVF BAR ENIRA), but your answer is funnier and therefore better.

Comment: I was thinking of that one as well, but there were so many possible options.

Answer (score 2):

After using Hint 1...

> We take every italicized letter to get *OEEAVINSRTHN*.

After using Hint 2...

> We realize that this is a word scramble, and so the answer must be **enervations** or **venerations**. I know my words don't include **all** the letters, but those are the longest possible words with the letters given. It could also be some other phrase... It's hard to narrow it down to one since there are so many possibilities...

Comment: I think you're missing a few letters.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I don't see any more letters which are italicized. Which ones do you see?

Comment: Go into Edit Mode, and look at the markup.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore fixed my solution.

Comment: You're missing the H in your anagram.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore There's no word that includes an H with all the other letters.

Comment: @smlee, it’s a phrase your looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the words were scrambled. There’s no Words Scrambled/Phrase Scramble tag.

Comment: Ah ok, no worries! I just got a bit confused. Thanks for clarifying. I edited my answer to address the confusion.